# What is the difference between a form submit event and a submit input click event?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit-button

A form named `form1` has a submit button named `button1`.

What is difference between `$("#form1").submit()` and  `$("#button1").click()`?

Answer (score 3):

If you check your html code you will see something like this `<form .... action="abcd.html">`. The action tag may or may not be a html page, it could be a .php, .aspx or just an url. `$("#form1").submit()` will post the data to this page/url and then that page will process the data.

`$("#form1").submit()` will post the data of the form to the url in the action tag of the form while `$("#button1").click()` will just trigger the click event.

Answer (score 2):

In you case there is no difference.

> The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to
>   submit a form. It can only be attached to `<form>` elements. Forms can
>   be submitted either by clicking an explicit `<input type="submit">`,
>   `<input type="image">`, or `<button type="submit">`, or by pressing Enter
>   when certain form elements have focus.

From [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) docs.

Using `$("#form1").submit()` you be able to submit form without submit button on the page.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#form1").submit()` just sends data to the server but `$("#button1").click()` fires button's click event and doesn't send any data to the server.

PS: if the button type is submit, it sends data to the server immediately.

Comment: If the button is a `<input type=submit>` then (unless the default action is suppressed) it will trigger the submit of the containing form.

Answer (score 1):

$("#form1").submit() submits the entire form to a Servlet or anything where as $("#button1").click() simply can be used to process anything like calling a function of javascript or even to submit the form.